# how can disable some column in QtableView pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I want to fill a tableView but I want to disable some columns so the user does not have the right to modify its contents.

```
def remplissageTableView(self):

        headers=["Janvier", "fevrier","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet", "Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Decembre"]
        rows=[]
        for i in range(5) :
            row = ["","","","","","","","","","","",""]
            rows.append(row)
        model =PrevisionTableModel(rows,headers) 
        self.tableView.setModel(model)
```

I initially want to have a tableView 12 column 5 line is a little stupid solution: p

Answer (score 3):

Use a [proxy model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractproxymodel.html) to control the [flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) on the table's model:

```
class ProxyModel(QtGui.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = set()

    def columnReadOnly(self, column):
        return column in self._columns

    def setColumnReadOnly(self, column, readonly=True):
        if readonly:
            self._columns.add(column)
        else:
            self._columns.discard(column)

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(ProxyModel, self).flags(index)
        if self.columnReadOnly(index.column()):
            flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return flags

...
model = PrevisionTableModel(rows, headers) 
self.proxy = ProxyModel(self)
self.proxy.setSourceModel(model)
self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy)
self.tableView.model().setColumnReadOnly(3, True)
```